# GDAL Java Bindings .SetWellKnownGeogCS error

Tags: gdal, java

I am using GDAL 2.3.0 and Java bindings from http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-3-0-mapserver-7-0-7.zip

I would like to create a `SpatialReference` from EPSG code.
This works fine:

```
hProj = new SpatialReference();
hProj.ImportFromEPSG(32632);
```

but

```
hProj = new SpatialReference();
hProj.SetWellKnownGeogCS("EPSG:32632");
```

generates

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: OGR Error: General Error
    at org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.SpatialReference_SetWellKnownGeogCS(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.osr.SpatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS(SpatialReference.java:473)
    at rgeo.lesson_x.JavaGDALTests.main(JavaGDALTests.java:22)
```

What could be the reason and how to fix that?